# Close All application click X Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I'm trying to change the names of the datagrid and labels in Form2 from Form1 based on the selection.

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();

            Form2 frm = new Form2();
            frm.Show();


        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 frm = new Form2();

            frm.dataGridView1.Columns["FirstName"].HeaderText = "Prenom";
            frm.dataGridView1.Columns["LastName"].HeaderText = "Nom";


            this.Hide();
            frm.Show();
        }
```

The above approach is working fine for me but I have a problem. When I click on `X` in the second/Form 2 it's just closing the `Form2` not the `Form1`. How can close all the application when i click on the `X`.

Is there any better way of doing this???  The reason why i'm not using I'm using Telerik and I don't find any option to add resource file in that. Please correct me if i'm wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to attach an event handler to the `Closed` event of the newly created form so that it closes the main form when it's closed:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();

    Form2 frm = new Form2();
    frm.FormClosed += (_, args) => this.Close(); //Added this method
    frm.Show();
}
```

Add that same method to the other click handler as well.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to close an application is to call the static method: [Application.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894.aspx)

Another method if you only want to close one single form would be to add a handler for the [FormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx) event and close the main form there.

Comment: You have to add an event handler to `FormClosing` either way.  Using `Application.Exit` in that handler isn't really all that much easier than closing the main form, and using `Exit` methods isn't really quite as good of a practice.